# What is this regular expression looking for

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
preg_match ("/[-_^%&().A-Z0-9]/", $file)
```

By the looks of it, I can see that the tail end is Anything A-Z and 0-9, but not sure for the beginning. Because ^ is not escaped so it could be a literal "^" or evaluated to a NOT, and same goes with ".", "(" and ")". So I am just a bit confused. Does having things inside the optional [] means things are literalized?

Comment: In a character set, (IE, [] bracketed set,) `^` and `.` do not need to be escaped. They mean, literally, the characters `^` and `.`.

Comment: `^` is a 'not' in a character class only if it's the FIRST character in the class, e.g. `[^A-Z]` (anything NOT a captital letter) v.s. `[A-Z^]` (capital letters and a literal `^`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just looks for one of the characters in the character class. I.e. one of:

- Hyphen-minus, underscore, caret, percent, ampersant, parentheses, dot
- Capital Latin letters
- Arabic numerals

`^` is only interpreted as negating a character class when at the very beginning of the class. `.` loses its special meaning inside character classes completely. So yes, in character classes many special regex characters are used literally. With exceptions, although the following list isn't exhaustive:

- Hyphen-minus (`-`) indicates a range when between two other characters (i.e. not at the start or end).
- The caret (`^`) as detailed above.
- Predefined character classes (e.g. `\w`) can be used as well, which will form a union with the characters from that class. So your character class could be shortened to `[-^%&().\w]`.

Comment: So that means if $file = ".abc", it will look for that "." also? hmmm, this confirms my suspection of what this regex is doing. Completely opposite of what I wanted.

Comment: Yes, it would match the dot in that case and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

`^` only has a special meaning inside `[]` if it is the *first* character.
`-` only has a special meaning inside `[]` if is *between two literal characters*.
`.`, `(` and `)` do not have a special meaning inside `[]`.

Just reading the basic information in the [docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) would tell you all this.

The regex just matches one of the characters in the class.