# Using Javascript and regex to modify the end of an URL

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to clean an URL (rss feed) such that after the last .rss (or.html) there are no further characters. I'm using the TryIt Editor on w3schools.com for testing. The following is my test code:

```
var str="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rsstest";
var patt1=/(.*[.rss|.html]).*/g;
var result = str.replace(patt1, "$1");
document.write(result);
```

The problem I am having is that the result shown is

```
http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rsstest
```

i.e. the "test" didn't get removed. I am wondering if someone could check my regex and explain what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Lose the [], escape the . to \. (Note this will also kill any query string params ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or some other testing service.  Forgive [my bias](http://w3fools.com/).

Some other answerers seem to have completely missed the point, so to explain your errors:

1. `[]` does not group—it defines a character class.  What you've written actually matches a single character, namely any of these: `.|hlmrst`.
2. Without the `$` anchor the two `.*`s may not match what you'd expect.

Try instead:

```
/(\.rss|\.html).*$/g
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32cCh/1/) demo.

Comment: Your answer is great, and since I work with sunny, and we both are kinda working on this issue together, we are looking for the last instance of .rss or .html, giving this example `http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss/cnn_world.rsstest` as second test, Your regex is not greedy, so it will look for the first iteration, and the .* will mean the second instance will be gone. Is there a way to flag it to be greedy, opposite of `?`

Comment: @Churk - Indeed there is. Use a negative lookahead assertion: ``/(\.rss|\.html)(?!.*\.rss|\.html).*$/g``. See http://jsfiddle.net/2f4jx/.

Answer (score 1):

should be `var patt1=/(\.rss|\.html).*$/g;` because . is special character

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466768/what-is-this-regular-expression-looking-for The "." is literalized within the []

Comment: @Stano my comment was referring to `because . is special character` and to what the op originally posted `var patt1=/(.*[.rss|.html]).*/g;`. The dot inside [] is not special characters, they are literalized by the [].

Answer (score 1):

try to use substring

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

and the lastindexof function

```
string.lastIndexOf(searchvalue)
```

combine it to:

```
var result = str.substring(0, str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("rss") + 3);
```

finally:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".rss") > str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".html")) 
{ result = str.substring(0, str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".rss") + 4);
} else {
result = str.substring(0, str.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".html") + 5);
}
```

Comment: edited to get rid of lower or upper case and my other errors ;-)

Comment: you can check wheter .rss or html is at the end by comparing the Index of both and then decide which string you use in lastIndexOf

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. I think a regex-based solution is more appropriate here. Interesting, though!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
var str="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rsstest";
str.replace(/test$/, "");
```

Comment: "test" is just my sample test, ideally it should replace anything after .rss

Comment: because it's may not "test" it can be anything.